# Why is sys/types included in every programming tutorial I see for no apparent reason?

Tags: c, systypes.h

Recently I have been watching a lot of socket programming tutorials for C. In every single one of those videos, the header file `sys/types` is included, but when I run the code that is written in the video without the `sys/types`, I get no warnings or errors. What does this header file do and why is it so common?

Comment: What tutorial? can you give more context?

Comment: Video programming tutorials on youtube for TCP socket programming @TonyTannous

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That file defines many types used in other files. On older systems, it was necessary to include it *before* other system headers.

From a man page for the `socket` syscall:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
       #include <sys/socket.h>

       int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);

...

NOTES
       POSIX.1 does not require the inclusion of <sys/types.h>, and this
       header file is not required on Linux.  However, some historical (BSD)
       implementations required this header file, and portable applications
       are probably wise to include it.
```

Comment: What types for which files

Comment: Just open that header, you’ll see. These types are used across many system headers.